# Display HTML content from Django

Tags: javascript, python, django

Whenever I receive an IPN in this url: `https://www.example.com/payment/notifications`, I want to display with JavaScript some HTML content to `https://www.example.com/stream/notifications/<token>`.

The goal is to display some successful donation message to a streamer whose token is `user.stream_token`. Then he can take that url and configure the alert with OBS.

This token is unique to every "streamer" and I can access it by doing `user.stream_token`

I manage the IPN from the server like this:

```
@csrf_exempt
def notifications(request):
    jrequest = json.loads(request.body)
    if request.method == "POST":
       if jrequest['action'] == 'payment.created':
           # some code
           return HttpResponse(status=200)
```

I want to run the JS function that displays the html content inside that block of code, because that's when I can confirm that a payment or donation has been approved.

I know that Django is server-side and JS is client-side so I cannot just run a JS function inside there.

Any ideas on how could I implement this in the simplest way possible? I read about WebSockets but the implementation is way too difficult for me to understand.

Answer (score 0):

If you are okay with your user having to send a request to trigger this change in the document, then you don't need a WebSocket. As we talked about last night on your question, you only need a WebSocket in a situation where you want your server to send your user a message without any prompting by the user.

However, if you are okay with the user having to send a request, you are on the right track. You are going to need to use ajax or fetch, etc. to make a request in your js to this view you are creating now. Then, depending on the data in the response from the view, you can render new elements in the document.

I am having a hard time understanding what the user is doing exactly in the frontend, and what you need to show them based on what event. If you can elaborate more we can keep working this out!

Comment: I'm trying to replicate Stream Alerts from here: https://www.buymeacoffee.com/settings/integrations   Here buymeacoffee provides you with and url you can set in OBS to make donation messages appear in your screen while you stream.

Comment: I am really struggling to implement this. I cant figure out an optimal and simple way of achieving this goal. I don't know how to make this connection with the client from the server, and at the same time display the contents of the payment/donation in the specific url I provide them. I would appreciate any help